# Embed custom control to CMFCPropertyGridCtrl Property Item

Tags: c++, mfc, propertygrid

I want to embed two generic buttons like "Select" and "Cancel" to `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` property line. Is there a painless way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution myself. You can use `OnCreateEditor` virtual method to send a custom control to a property. Note, that it will be shown on property edit. Another important note, that `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` calls `OnCreateEditor` each time the user edits the property but before the control is destroyed it deletes the last received `CWnd` object itself. You should consider that. I have found no notes about that in MSDN `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` documentation (you know what to say).

Comment: Is it not possible to provide some sample code?